# Python Kafka consumer not reading messages as they arrive

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am just getting started with Kafka, kafka-python. In the code below, I am trying to read the messages as they arrive. But for some reason, the consumer seems to be waiting till a certain number of messages accrue before fetching them.

I initially thought it was because of the producer which was publishing in batch. When I ran "kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-servers  --topic ", I could see every message that was being received as soon as it got published ( as seen on the consumer console)

But the python script is not able to receive the messages in the same way.

```
def run():
    success_consumer = KafkaConsumer('success_logs',
                                     bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BROKER_URL,
                                     group_id=None,
                                     fetch_min_bytes=1,
                                     fetch_max_bytes=10,
                                     enable_auto_commit=True)
    #dummy poll
    success_consumer.poll()
    for msg in success_consumer:
        print(msg)

    success_consumer.close()
```

Can someone point out what configuration changed with KafkaConsumer? Why is it not able to read messages like "kafka-console-consumer" ?

Comment: What happens when you give a group id as a string?

Answer (score 1):

The KafkaConsumer class also has a `fetch_max_wait_ms` [parameter](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.4/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html). You should set it to 0

```
success_consumer = KafkaConsumer(...,fetch_max_wait_ms=0)
```

Comment: Adding this did not help. Consumer is still waiting to accrue certain number of messages. Besides, I have already specified a really low fetch_max_bytes=10. It should override the fetch_max_wait_ms considering the messages are certainly longer than 10 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late for OP but for anyone else having this problem, adding a timeout like so worked for me:

```
consumer.poll(timeout_ms= 1000)
```